# Interacting with a Listbox on a Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I am using the following code to add a listbox to a dynamically created sheet:

```
    Set stuListBox = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ListBox.1", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=686.3, Top:=188.1, Width:=145, Height:=100)
        stuListBox.Placement = xlFreeFloating

    ' Add items to listbox
    Dim i As Variant
    For Each i In rosterSh.Range("A2:A" & lastStuRow)
        With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Listbox1").Object
            .AddItem i.Value
        End With
    Next i
```

where the items added to the listbox are from a specified range on a different sheet. All of this works fine, but I can't interact with the listbox on the dynamically created sheet - it is static (I can't scroll through the list items or select any). How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the sheet protected?

Comment: Nope. I can edit the cells and interact with everything else on the sheet (command buttons as well).

Comment: Toggle after/ at end of your your code between  visible = false and visible = true